# Graphics Card Adapter Is Facing Backwards

Tags: hardware-failure

I think the graphic card adapter is facing backward. I think if you place a graphics card there it would be facing inside the case instead of outside the case, please help me. I really like to make my pc a gaming rig but i dont even know if a graphics card would fit

My pc is a NEC Mate model MS-7480N1 SFF i think(according to speccy software)

[image]

Comment: From what I gather this is a very old computer from 2011, with just 2 GB of RAM and a 2nd Generation Core-i CPU. Makes no sense to put in a proper video-card. Will remain an ancient, slow computer unsuitable for any form of serious gaming.
The video-card goes into the cage (top of your photo) and the cage fits in the slot in the motherboard. Be advised that most gaming-cards will not fit and that the powersupply of this computer will not have the juice to feed most of the cards that do fit. (And the powersupply will not have the extra 6 or 8 pin power-connector that the video-card needs.)

Comment: Even if you can make it all fit the card will probably overheat because these small SFF cases have awful cooling. There are designed for standard office use. Not to run power-hungry (== running hot) gaming video-cards.

Comment: Ok... I better buy a new one then. Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your photos, you have various slots.

[image: the photo]

From top to bottom:

- Riser assembly:

  - PCI Express 1x (white)
  - PCI (not PCI Express, white)
- Motherboard:

  - PCI Express 16x (black)
  - Proprietary Riser Slot (white)

The proprietary riser slot appears to be a reverse-mounted PCI slot. However, because it must also carry PCIe 1x, it is most certainly not PCI-compatible.

Theoretically, the PCIe 16x slot could host a graphics card. However, there is simply not enough space to accommodate a powerful graphics card. You can mount a single-slot low-profile graphics card, like some GeForce GT 1030 models.

While this will tremendously increase the gaming performance of this PC, it won’t be enough to play recent games with higher quality.